# Listview.builder causes RenderFlex overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the code below that I'm using to generate a list view

```
class PostListsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostListsWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostListsWidget createState() => _PostListsWidget();

}

class _PostListsWidget extends State<PostListsWidget> {
  static const List<PostListModel> _latestPosts = [
    PostListModel(post: 'this is a test as.', votes: 453, like: 1, iconID: 0xe908),
    PostListModel(post: 'this is a test as', votes: 2, like: 2, iconID: 0xe904),
    PostListModel(post: 'this is a test a', votes: 324, like: 1, iconID: 0xe908),
    PostListModel(post: 'this is a test s', votes: 435, like: 3, iconID: 0xe90d),
  ];

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, PostListModel postList){
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,   
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
         Flexible( 
        
          child: Container(   
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),  
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children:  <Widget> [
                PentEmotionWidget(iconid:  postList.iconID),
                Expanded(child:   Text(
                    postList.post, 
                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                  )    )
              
              ],
            )  ,
          )
         ),
          Flexible(
         
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
              
                children:  <Widget> [         
                 Expanded(child: 
                   PentLikesCountWidget(votes: postList.votes),
                 ),
                  PentLikesActionWidget(like: postList.like)       
                ],
                ),
            )
          )
          
        ],
     ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _latestPosts.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
        _buildListItem(context, _latestPosts[index]),   
      );
  }
}
```

The code works but the last tile is cut

[image]

I've tried playing around with Expanded and Flexible but that doesn't make a difference. Seems like the problem is the List cannot scroll therefore it cuts the content overflow. Can anybody help?

Have to add random text here because SO won't let me post without adding more 'details'

Comment: Hi @mr_j  add Flex to flexible!

Comment: @PradipD. Tried that. Doesn't make a difference. I think I'll have to rewrite the way I've done it

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is correct, then you only need to wrap you ListView.builder inside a Container/SizedBox and give it to some height

```
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: ListView.builder(
   ...
  )
)
```

If that's not the case, maybe try not using expanded or flexible.

Comment: I've figured out what the problem is. I've put the Listview.builder widget inside a column in the main.dart file. The column cannot expand hence it causes the issue

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. cool.